# error while parsing rss feed for stackoverflow.com

Tags: android, parsing, rss

i am trying to create rss feeds app that parses all the websites supporting feed. i used Jsoup for this purpose. and parsed for different type of rss in this way

```
org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");  
org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("link[type=application/atom+xml]");
```

it parses various websites like engadget.com, ndtv.com etc but when i tried to pase websites like stackoverflow.com or 1up.com i got the following error.

> thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40efe378)

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/rss
```

searching for error #1 didnt yield even 1 results.
searching for eroror #2 had many. all stated to use http:// before any websites url like

```
http://1up.com
```

but then too the error persists. and i had already implemented this before since all other websites rss are parsed.
this is my logcat for 1up.com rss feed.

```
D/URL Length(4097): 14
D/url name(4097): http://1up.com
D/No of RSS links found(4097):  1
W/dalvikvm(4097): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40efe378)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(4097): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/rss
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.maulik.rss.RssParser.getXmlFromUrl(RssParser.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.maulik.rss.RssParser.getRSSFeed(RssParser.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.maulik.rss.RSS_AddNewSiteActivity$loadRSSFeed.doInBackground(RSS_AddNewSiteActivity.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.maulik.rss.RSS_AddNewSiteActivity$loadRSSFeed.doInBackground(RSS_AddNewSiteActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: can anyone tell me how to view rss file for 1up.com when i click on this link http://feeds.feedburner.com/1up/ALLPS3/content the contents are shown not in xml. if theres anyway i can have a look in xml then i can even try to figure out the problem

Comment: i think i found the problem, sites engadget.com uses <channel> and i parsed using this itself. but websites like stackoverflow.com feeds have <entry>.

now can anyone tell me how can i stop parsing feeds with <entry>tag?

Comment: When do you get the errors? When you try to get the links to feeds or when you try to parse the raw feeds?

Comment: @z2s8 when i try to get the rss url, i used log message to display the links found or not. so for 1up.com log message was 'no of rss link found:1' and afterwards i got the error. but for stackoverflow.com rss, it stated that no rss link found and the error showed up.

so its the parsing thats causing the error. but the rss of engadget and 1up.com is the same structure http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml http://www.1up.com/rss then too engadget's rss are properly parsed

Comment: Seems to me that `IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.` indicates that the problem is caused by **invalid** (or null) RSS **address**. From 1up.com : `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="/rss?x=1" />` and from your logcat output seems the **request goes to wrong address:**  http://rss?x=1 (or same w/o http) so instead of the relative link 1up.com/rss, it handles the link as an absolute one. *You could detect relative links and convert them to absolute  ones before parsing feeds.*

Comment: hi @z2s8 and thanks for the reply, this only would seem as a solution to the problem. but i didnt get how you got to know from my logcat that request is going to wrong address rss?x=1..?? after you commented i read the source of 1up and saw the href rss?x=1.

the 2nd line in logcat **D/url name(4097): http://1up.com** is what the user has entered in the textbox

Comment: @z2s8 thanks dude,you were totally right, i was calling just the href method and parsing only the href attribute. since engadget had href as its entire website address it used to parse. but 1up had href just /rss?x=1 so it didnt parse. the error's gone for 1up.com which uses <channel> tag but still persist for stackoverflow which uses <entry> tag in rss feed. put your answer in answer so that i can accept it!

Comment: posted as answer, with additional information for your tag problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.` indicates that the problem is caused by **invalid** (or null) RSS **address**.

From http://1up.com: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="/rss?x=1" />` and from your logcat output seems the **request goes to wrong address**: http:// rss?x=1 (or same w/o http) so instead of the relative link 1up.com/rss, it handles the link as an absolute one. 
*You could detect relative links and convert them to absolute ones before parsing feeds.*

While some sites use the [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) standard, some others use the [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) standard. **RSS and Atom feeds' [tags are different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#RSS_Compared_to_Atom).**
*You may need to create different parsing algorithms for each feed type.*

Comment: hi thanks for the help, i have already created parsers for both type of rss standards. its all working fine now!